# How to get the ip address of machine using java program in linux

Tags: java

How to get the ip address of machine using java program?
I knw how to do in windows.i want to do in linux using java program

Comment: Just being curious, how will you do it in windows?

Comment: hey @01101988, have you tried anything yet ?

Answer (score 3):

The following example program lists all the network interfaces and their addresses on a machine:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class ListNets {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
            displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
    }

    static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
        out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
        out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
        for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {
            out.printf("InetAddress: %s\n", inetAddress);
        }
        out.printf("\n");
     }
}
```

The following is sample output from the example program:

```
Display name: TCP Loopback interface
Name: lo
InetAddress: /127.0.0.1

Display name: Wireless Network Connection
Name: eth0
InetAddress: /192.0.2.0
```

Source:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html

Answer (score 0):

If its java, it'll work same on both operating systems. Are you searching for an `ipconfig` equivalent command in linux? Its `ifconfig`